# If a series converges and its sequence is monotonic, why it can not be a monotonic increasing function?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have been wondering this for a while
If $$\sum a_{n}$$ converges and {$a_{n}$} is a monotonic function
Why must {$a_{n}$} be decreasing. Why can't it be increasing

Comment: It can be increasing. Consider$$a_n=-\frac1{n^2}$$

Comment: @Peter Foreman And if we restrict the sequence so that $a_{n}$ is positive for every $n$
Do your answers hold?

Comment: No because we know that $a_n\to0$ and so assuming that $a_n$ is non-negative it cannot increase towards $0$ and so must be decreasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer this question in a more intuitive, informal way. Imagine all $a_n>0$ and $(a_n)$ increasing. Then

$\sum a_n = a_1+ a_2+\dots \ge a_1+a_1+ a_1\cdots =\infty$.

The mathemetically correct answer is that for every convergent series, it is necessary the underlying sequence $(a_n)$ is a null sequence.

If it's increasing and strinctly greater zero the sequence can't converge to $0$, i.e. the series must diverge.